# Printable Jquery Layout

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, layout

right now, i'am using jquery layout UI to manage my website layout.
my layout is similar to [complex demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/complex.html) with customization, i only used north, west, and center pane.

what i'am trying to do is how to create a printable layout like [printable demo](http://layout.jquery-dev.net/demos/printable.html) here.

i've tried it but it's doesn't works, the toolbar on the top and sidebar in the west is still come up when i click print preview,
maybe anyone can help me??

thanks in advanced..

Comment: Please post some code you came up with.

Comment: there's no code for the print function, it's the usual print Ctrl + P
and as for the css, it was the same as the printable demo i post above.

for the layout script, i copy paste from the complex demo, so i think it was same too..

maybe you can help me?

Comment: Then could you share the code (e.g. css, javascript, html, etc) that you came up with?